# Visualizing depth image OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visualization, depth

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840013/opencv-how-to-visualize-a-depth-image), however in this image I only have a subset of pixels with a valid depth and the rest are set to zero.

For example, here is the rgb:

[image]

where all the white pixels have no depth (depth value of 0). If I use the method in the linked question, which is:

```
double min;
double max;
cv::minMaxIdx(map, &min, &max);
cv::Mat adjMap;
cv::convertScaleAbs(map, adjMap, 255 / max);
cv::imshow("Out", adjMap);
```

I get the following image, from which it is not very clear to see the depth differences:

[image]

The min and max depth values on the object are 601 and 654 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try subtracting the minimum first, then scale to your data range:

```
double min;
double max;
cv::minMaxIdx(map, &min, &max);
map -= min;
cv::Mat adjMap;
cv::convertScaleAbs(map, adjMap, 255.0 / double(max-min) );
cv::imshow("Out", adjMap);
```