# Density based heatmap of an image-Opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-processing, heatmap

Im looking to implement a heatmap of a video in OpenCv...Im aiming for three colours where colour1 represents maximum density,colour 2 represents lower density and so on...Any idea how I can go about this??Im not able to find any generic links on how to design a heatmap on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

[OpenCV: How to visualize a depth image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840013/opencv-how-to-visualize-a-depth-image/13843342#13843342)

OpenCV has (in the contrib module) a color mapping algorithm, together with some pre-defined maps, very similar to what you'd find in Matlab.

Comment: Thanks...Thats is what Im looking for..I will repost here if I have any more doubts..@sammy

Comment: I wasnt able to get good results..@Sammy....Could you help me with the general algorithm(in words) of the code you have posted in that answer..Thanks!!