# Applying Color Map to Depth Image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect, depth

So I'm playing around with a Kinect and some code that I found online to visualize the depth image. I was looking at this thread ([OpenCV: How to visualize a depth image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840013/opencv-how-to-visualize-a-depth-image)) and I'm trying to use the applyColorMap function, however whenever it gets called, it triggers a breakpoint giving me the error: "HEAP[OpenCVKinect.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 004A0000, 009206D8 )"

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong; I'm following the suggestions in the mentioned thread pretty much as it is.

```
    dataStream = myDataCap.getData();
    std::cout << dataStream.size() <<  std::endl;
    dataStream[0];
    if(dataStream.size()==1 && !dataStream[0].empty())
    {
        double min;
        double max;
        Mat datamat = dataStream[C_DEPTH_STREAM];
        minMaxIdx(datamat, &min, &max);
        Mat adjMap;
        datamat.convertTo(adjMap,CV_8UC1, 255 / (max-min), -min);
        Mat falseColorsMap;
        applyColorMap(adjMap, falseColorsMap, COLORMAP_AUTUMN);
        imshow("Out", falseColorsMap);



        imshow("Depth", dataStream[C_DEPTH_STREAM]);
```